# Does -mxs command line switch always close 3DSMax?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I’d like to run a very simple script command through the command line, and the -mxs switch appears to do exactly that. However, everytime I use it 3DSMax 2011 automatically shuts down afterwards. Whether I use the quitMax call or not. Is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 3):

Put the command in a file and use the '-u' option to execute the MAXScript file instead.